# Exportar proyecto como diagrama de flujo

Tags: python, visual-studio

Verán, tengo un proyecto en Python que quiero pasar a diagrama en flujo.
Para ello, estoy en Visual Studio y he instalado py2flowchart.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto me genera una representación en diagrama de flujo:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero la historia es que necesito exportar dicho diagrama (ya sea como una imagen o como un archivo de diagrama de flujo).
¿Como hago para exportar el diagrama de flujo resultante?

Comment: ¿Cómo lo has hecho para pegar la imagen en la pregunta?

Comment: Ese paquete de python está pensado para generar el markdown y luego importarlo en typora, code2flow y similares, imagino que en VS te está importando algún render y es el que te está generando la imagen

Comment: @abulafia Pantallazo con Impr Pant. El problema es que con proyectos más grandes no me va a caber todo el diagrama en un solo pantallazo.

Comment: @CésarGonzález ¿Y como se haría eso?

Comment: @MiguelAlparez pero para que querrías hacerlo? A fin de cuentas sería lo mismo que consigues desde VS pero con un paso más. Tendrías que generar el markdown e irte a otra herramienta para generar la imagen y exportarla desde allí. Para eso casi mejor hacerlo desde VS, no? O que buscas hacer?

Comment: @CésarGonzález La historia es que ya he creado dentro de Visual Studio el diagrama de flujo, pero lo que no he conseguido es exportarlo como un fichero ajeno a VS. Quiero pasarle a otra persona el diagrama de flujo del proyecto, sin necesidad pasarle el código python.

Comment: @MiguelAlparez y por qué no te sirve la misma captura de pantalla que has adjuntado aquí? Te serviría exportar el markdown?

Comment: [la aplicación debe registrar el peso de los vehículos y catalogarlos como vehiculos livianos o
pesados, tambien registrará ingreso estimado de personas según el peso del vehículo
Al finalizar el tiempo de operación se debe mostrar resumen con los de datos registrados]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Revisando la documentación de ese paquete he visto que lo que buscas está resuelto, ya que es capaz de generar un documento html que ya incorpora flowchart.js de cara a interpretar el markdown.

```
from py2flowchart import pyfile2flowchart

pyfile2flowchart('titanic.py', 'export.html')
# donde titanic.py es tu script y export.html el archivo de salida
```

Ten en cuenta que aparentemente y según su propia documentación, es una librería muy muy muy limitada y no va a interpretar cosas como breaks y continues.

Comment: Así que así era. El metodo es bastante raro, ya que hay que crear otro fichero python y en el introducir este código. Además, veo que es solo mediante html. No es posible pasarlo a jpg o png. Aún así, gracias por solucionar mi problema.

Answer (score 0):

```py
from py2flowchart import pyfile2flowchart
```

```
pyfile2flowchart('anestesicos.py', 'export.html')
```

Donde `anestesicos.py` es tu script con el diagrama de árbol y `export.html` el archivo de salida